# Create regex match pattern from a string

Tags: c#, regex, vb.net

Is there a way, using c# or vb, to take a string (in this case a phone number) and construct a regex match string from it, so that it also ignores spaces or other characters in there?

So a match would be found on all of these assuming the input string was 01789000111 :-

01789 000111      OR      01789 000 111      OR      01789 00 01 11      OR      (01789) 000111

Comment: Why do you need a regex for this? Just remove all spaces and braces from 
input string and compare.

Comment: Because I am using it with Linq - e.g. Qry = Qry.Where(Function(x) rgx.IsMatch(If(x.Tel1, "")) Or rgx.IsMatch(If(x.Tel2, "")) Or rgx.IsMatch(If(x.Mob1, "")) Or rgx.IsMatch(If(x.Mob2, "")))

Comment: 'or other characters in there' - so that would give a match `0a1b7c8d9e0f0g0h1i1j1k1` ?

Comment: @user9310259 I think you should add this info to the question

Comment: Ok.  So by other characters in there, what I mean is I have phone numbers stored in the database, and not all are a constant string of digits. Some have spaces in, some have brackets in there etc - For example - (000) 00 00 00 - All Iwant is to be able to pass in a string to match with such as 01234998877 and any matches found Excluding spaces brackets etc will be matched - does that make sense?

Comment: Replace whitespace/() then test for equality?

Comment: I would ask myself why are they so differently formatted in the database in the first place. Isnt there a way for you to store them identically?

Comment: If I could reformat in the database I would but its an inherited project so I can't unfortunately so stuck with the hard way

Comment: @user9310259 you can run `Update` command on your phone numbers that cleans up whitespace and special chars

Answer (score 3):

Remove the non-digits with a regex replace then compare:

```
var match = Regex.Replace(src, @"\D+", "") == target;
```

Alternatively, you could convert the target digits to a pattern and test:

```
var ans = Regex.IsMatch(src, Regex.Replace(target, @"\d", @"\D?$0\D?"))
```

If you are comparing a lot of `src` strings to the target, you should probably create a compiled `Regex` from the target:

```
var tpattern = new Regex(Regex.Replace(target, @"\d", @"\D?$0\D?"), RegexOptions.Compiled);

var ans = tpattern.IsMatch(src);
```